# How to transform stored values in a DICOM file to real world units?

Tags: image, image-processing, dicom, medical, pydicom

I am trying to calculate radioactivity concentrations on a PET DICOM image using either Matlab or python. I have read in the DICOM standard that

```
(0028,1053) Rescale Slope    
(0028,1052) Rescale Intercept
```

can be used to map the stored 16 bit uints (in my case) to real units. The files also contain the following elements:

```
(0040,9096) Real World Value Mapping Sequence    
(0028,9145) Pixel Value Transformation Sequence
```

as parts of a `(5200,9230) Per Frame Functional Groups Sequence` (for each frame in a dynamic measurement) or a `(5200,9229) Shared Functional Groups Sequence` (for static measurements). These sequences also contain rescale slopes and intercepts. The values match with each other (for a given frame, the `(0040,9096) Real World Value Mapping Sequence` and `(0028,9145) Pixel Value Transformation Sequence` values are the same) but they don't match the values of tha "main" slope and intercept (that are attributes of the PET Image module). For example after reading a dynamic multi-frame file with pydicom as `ds`:

```
#This is the "main" slope, part of the PET Image module    
>ds.RescaleSlope  
Out[31]: "0.478081"

#This is a dynamic image, for a static image SharedFunctionalGroupsSequence would be used
>ds.PerFrameFunctionalGroupsSequence[0].PixelValueTransformationSequence[0].RescaleSlope
Out[34]: "104.435089"

>ds.PerFrameFunctionalGroupsSequence[0].RealWorldValueMappingSequence[0].RealWorldValueSlope
Out[38]: 104.43508911132812
```

My question is the following: How do I correctly apply these transformations to get real world units (e.g.: Bq/ml as described in the header) from the pixel values? Do I need to multiply with both ds.RescaleSlope and RealWorldValueSlope? (the intercepts are always 0 in my case). This seems counterintuitive as the dicom standard [states](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.7.6.16.2.html) that these two values don't really have anything to do with each other, but then what does ds.RescaleSlope do?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If following David Clunie [in this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.protocols.dicom/n5ybyj1Psno/5WCR5JmXTb0J), `Real World Value Mapping Sequence` shall be used in this case, Rescale/Slope being a fallback if this is not supported. I haven't used `Real World Value Mapping Sequence` myself (always applied the modality LUT in a display pipeline if present), so I'm not completely sure about this, though...